# Really simple error; I've probably forgotten a semicolon

Tags: c, gcc

I'm getting loads of errors like these:

```
gfx.h:48: error: syntax error before 'buffer'

gfx.h:48: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'buffer'

gfx.h:48: warning: data definition has no type or storage class

gfx.h:73: error: syntax error before 'uint16_t'

gfx.h:73: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union

gfx.h:74: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'visible_lines_per_frame'

gfx.h:74: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
...
```

I'm a bit tired, so I can't figure out what could be causing these.

This is the definition of `buffer` (starting at line 43, going to line 57):

```
/* 8-bit architecture (not yet used.) */
#if   PROC_BIT_SIZE == 8
uint8_t buffer[GFX_SIZE];
# define GFX_PIXEL_ADDR(x,y) (x / 8) + (y * (GFX_WIDTH / 8))
/* 16-bit architecture: dsPIC */
#elif  PROC_BIT_SIZE == 16
uint16_t buffer[GFX_SIZE / 2];
# define GFX_PIXEL_ADDR(x,y) (x / 16) + (y * (GFX_WIDTH / 16))
/* 32-bit architecture: AVR32(?), STM32 */
#elif  PROC_BIT_SIZE == 32
uint32_t buffer[GFX_SIZE / 4];
# define GFX_PIXEL_ADDR(x,y) (x / 32) + (y * (GFX_WIDTH / 32))
/* Other, unknown bit size.*/
#else
# error "processor bit size not supported"
#endif
```

(It's designed to support multiple architectures 8-bit MCUs to 32-bit MCUs.)

I've defined uint8_t etc. because the GCC I'm using doesn't seem to have a stdint.h header.

Here is how I have defined uint8_t etc.

```
/* 
 * stdint.h support.
 * If your compiler has stdint.h, uncomment HAS_STDINT.
 */
//#define HAS_STDINT
#ifndef HAS_STDINT
// D'oh, compiler doesn't support STDINT, so create our own,
// 'standard' integers.
# if PROC_BIT_SIZE == 8 || PROC_BIT_SIZE == 16
typedef char int8_t;
typedef int int16_t;
typedef long int32_t;
typedef long long int64_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint16_t;
typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
# elif PROC_BIT_SIZE == 32
typedef char int8_t;
typedef short int16_t;
typedef int int32_t; // usually int is 32 bits on 32 bit processors, but this may need checking
typedef long int64_t;
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
typedef unsigned long uint64_t;
# endif
#else
# include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: @Thomas, can you add some line numbers so we can match up the messages with the code?  And show us the code where the errors are actually coming from?  Oh - and your code that defines `uint8_t`, et al.

Comment: Can you show us how you defined uint8_t ?

Comment: @Thomas, despite your assumption that you've defined `uint8_t` and friends, the compiler seems to disagree. Can you also show the code you're defining these in?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this excerpt; can you include some more context? It's possible that an error before these lines is actually being reported here. You might wish to help localize the error by stripping your file down to just a few lines that still give you the same error; that can help you see where the error actually is.

Comment: As an aside, you should be using `signed char` for `int8_t` - plain `char` is special, and can be either signed or unsigned.  Also, the 32 bit branch should be using `long long` for the 64 bit types too.

Comment: You should probably also use the `INT_MAX` etc. macros to decide how to define these types, rather than having to define your own macro for what type of system you're on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apparently have solved my problem.

My mistake was to not declare PROC_BIT_SIZE before the "typedef" definitions of uint8_t and friends. The preprocessor therefore ignored the declarations, causing the error.

Just a blunder of my own making.

Comment: One way to avoid that in the future is to add an `#else` section to the `#if PROC_BIT_SIZE == ` block that says `#error PROC_BIT_SIZE not defined`.

Answer (score 1):

The `warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union` implies that you've left a semicolon off at the end of a `struct` or `union` defined earlier in the same file, or in another header that was included earlier. This would result in malformed statements such as:

```
struct S { ... } uint8_t buffer[GFX_SIZE];
```